# Removing a Shape from a Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-drawable, shapes

How To Remove A shape example quadrant from the corner of a drawable, I found many examples for a circular corner, but none where i could remove the radius of a corner of a layout.

Like This:

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this just by using the drawable.

This is the code for the rounded corners which is not on the same lines as what I need-:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" 
        android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Try to include some sample code of what you've actually tried.

Comment: @RickSuggs Thanks for the reply, I have tried to play with the circular border to make it work, I did not accomplish anything similar to what I need, so did not include any code snippet

Comment: Start with a small sample project with at least the rectangle drawn and post it on github, it would be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="75dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#95FFEE" />
            <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#C0BFBF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="26dp"
        android:height="26dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#C0BFBF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="26dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="26dp"
        android:height="26dp"
        android:gravity="end">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#C0BFBF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="26dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:gravity="end">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="26dp"
        android:height="26dp"
        android:gravity="end|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#C0BFBF" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="26dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:gravity="end|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="26dp"
        android:height="26dp"
        android:gravity="start|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#C0BFBF" />
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="26dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:gravity="start|bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```